# Flutter / dart exception geolocation error

Tags: dart, geolocation, flutter

i have a problem with flutter / dart using geolocation . I have followed instructions from one Udemy course but i have expirienced this error. The package is uploaded and code completly resembles to the instructors code although it wont work . I have also tried to clean build file by entering : "flutter clean" in terminal, also didnt fix the issue . If i need to post some more info let me know . Thanks for your time . Cheers

```
[VERBOSE-2:shell.cc(181)] Dart Error: Unhandled exception:
RangeError (index): Invalid value: Valid value range is empty: 0
#0      List.[] (dart:core/runtime/libgrowable_array.dart:142:60)
#1      _LocationInputState._getStaticMap (file:///Users/matija/Documents/Development/artapica/lib/widgets/form_inputs/location.dart:64:37)
<asynchronous suspension>
#2      _LocationInputState._updateLocation (file:///Users/matija/Documents/Development/artapica/lib/widgets/form_inputs/location.dart:124:7)
#3      ChangeNotifier.notifyListeners (package:flutter/src/foundation/change_notifier.dart:161:21)
#4      FocusNode._notify (package:flutter/src/widgets/focus_manager.dart:103:5)
#5      FocusManager._update (package:flutter/src/widgets/focus_manager.dart:449:20)
#6      _microtaskLoop (dart:async/schedule_microtask.dart:41:21)
#7      _startMicrotaskLoop (dart:async/schedule_microtask.dart:50:5)
```

Location.dart

```
class LocationInput extends StatefulWidget

 {
  final Function setLocation;
  final Product product;

  LocationInput(this.setLocation, this.product);

  @override
  State<StatefulWidget> createState() {
    return _LocationInputState();
  }
}

class _LocationInputState extends State<LocationInput> {
  Uri _staticMapUri;
  LocationData _locationData;
  final FocusNode _addressInputFocusNode = FocusNode();
  final TextEditingController _addressInputController = 
 TextEditingController();

  @override
 void initState() {
   _addressInputFocusNode.addListener(_updateLocation);
    if (widget.product != null) {
     _getStaticMap(widget.product.location.address, geocode: false);
   }
    super.initState();
 }

 @override
  void dispose() {
   _addressInputFocusNode.removeListener(_updateLocation);
     super.dispose();
   }
  void _getStaticMap(String address,
       {bool geocode = true, double lat, double lng}) async {
       if (address.isEmpty) {
       setState(() {
        _staticMapUri = null;
      });
     widget.setLocation(null);
     return;
    }
     if (geocode) {
       final Uri uri = Uri.https(
        'maps.googleapis.com',
       '/maps/api/geocode/json',
    {'address': address, 'key': 'MYKEY'},
  );
  final http.Response response = await http.get(uri);
  final decodedResponse = json.decode(response.body);
  final formattedAddress =
      decodedResponse['results'][0]['formatted_address'];
  final coords = decodedResponse['results'][0]['geometry']['location'];
  _locationData = LocationData(
      address: formattedAddress,
      latitude: coords['lat'],
      longitude: coords['lng']);
} else if (lat == null && lng == null) {
  _locationData = widget.product.location;
} else {
  _locationData =
      LocationData(address: address, latitude: lat, longitude: lng);
}

if (mounted) {
  final StaticMapProvider staticMapViewProvider =
      StaticMapProvider('MYKEY');
  final Uri staticMapUri = staticMapViewProvider.getStaticUriWithMarkers([
    Marker('position', 'Position', _locationData.latitude,
        _locationData.longitude)
  ],
      center: Location(_locationData.latitude, _locationData.longitude),
      width: 500,
      height: 300,
      maptype: StaticMapViewType.roadmap);
  widget.setLocation(_locationData);

  setState(() {
    _addressInputController.text = _locationData.address;
    _staticMapUri = staticMapUri;
      });
    }
   }
         Future<String> _getAddress(double lat, double lng) async {
         final uri = Uri.https(
          'maps.googleapis.com',
           '/maps/api/geocode/json',
             {
          'latlng': '${lat.toString()},${lng.toString()}',
           'key': 'MYKEY'
      },
     );
    final http.Response response = await http.get(uri);
    final decodedResponse = json.decode(response.body);
     final formattedAddress = decodedResponse['results'][0] 
     ['formatted_address'];
      return formattedAddress;
    }

   void _getUserLocation() async {
final location = geoloc.Location();
final currentLocation = await location.getLocation();
final address = await _getAddress(
    currentLocation['latitude'], currentLocation['longitude']);
_getStaticMap(address,
    geocode: false,
    lat: currentLocation['latitude'],
    lng: currentLocation['longitude']);
   }

  void _updateLocation() {
if (!_addressInputFocusNode.hasFocus) {
  _getStaticMap(_addressInputController.text);
    }
    }

   @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Column(
      children: <Widget>[
        EnsureVisibleWhenFocused(
          focusNode: _addressInputFocusNode,
      child: TextFormField(
        focusNode: _addressInputFocusNode,
        controller: _addressInputController,
        validator: (String value) {
          if (_locationData == null || value.isEmpty) {
            return 'No valid location found.';
          }
        },
        decoration: InputDecoration(labelText: 'Address'),
      ),
    ),
    SizedBox(height: 10.0),
    FlatButton(
      child: Text('Locate User'),
      onPressed: _getUserLocation,
    ),
    SizedBox(
      height: 10.0,
    ),
    _staticMapUri == null
        ? Container()
        : Image.network(_staticMapUri.toString())
  ],
);
  }
    }
```

Comment: can't provide any help to you unless you share location.dart

Comment: I have added location.dart . :)

Comment: Thanks. The error points to line 64 and 124, could you tell me which are those lines. PS. you seemed to have posted the code as an answer instead of editing the original post, so I've edited your post for you to include it, it is just waiting for peer review.

Comment: Also please provide an example of the JSON that you receive

Comment: While providing you a JSON , i inserted line  : print(decoded respose); after final decodedResponse = json.decode(response.body); . I found out that i'm surrpassing daily response limit of 1 . That was setted by google recently . . .. .

Comment: Thought the issue might lay there. Glad you figured it out yourself

Answer (score 0):

While providing you a JSON , i inserted line  : print(decoded respose); 
after final decodedResponse = json.decode(response.body); .

I found out that i'm surrpassing daily response limit of 1 . That was setted by google recently . . .. .

this was error message :

flutter: {error_message: You have exceeded your daily request quota for this API. If you did not set a custom daily request quota, verify your project has an active billing account: http://g.co/dev/maps-no-account, results: [], status: OVER_QUERY_LIMIT}

Thank you for your time once more. Cheers